# Customizing wordpress for building a CMS

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework, cakephp, content-management-system

I am  working on building a CMS where the user will get a control of all the components he wants to use,without using any templates.He will have a dashboard and a control panel which will include the components like menus,galleries,text boxes etc.He will have a easy to use drag and drop UI to work on his website.
Now I am researching on using either a framework like **Cake/Zend** or customizing wordpress to achive the goal.
I would like the **experts to guide which would be more feasible**? Is customizing wordpress,which is theme based a easy way(**By easy I mean achievable in a decent period of time**) or building it from scratch using a framework?
If I think about wordpress it uses structured templates which allows us to change the themes easily.Now I would like to by pass this and allow user to just use a drag and drop approach to build a website.The themes wont come into picture in our scenario,so can I eliminate them?.
**But I am not sure if wordpress allows this as its entirely based on structured themes/templates**.
(The idea is very raw and spare me if it sounds odd.work is in progress for it)

Comment: I would defintely don't go for wordpress. Wordpress is a blogging system and a horrible CMS. It does support basic functionality for static pages but was not built for CMS funcionality. Even if you manage to get it working you might run in to trouble later when you want to add functinoality that is not supported by wordpress.

Comment: @Neograph734 thank you for your views.I was suggested wordpress for the reason that it is stable in the sense of handling multiple websites and has a subtle core functionality.But yes modifying something may land you in trouble more often or less.Hence i would like to have opinions of the experts who might have worked on something similar.

Comment: How about http://concrete5.org/ ?

Comment: @jakenoble looks good,but i will need to think about the learning curve needed for whatever I use.will go through it.Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know why the down vote was,so that I can improve the question. "Constructive critisism is always welcome"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having built tons of WordPress sites and several fully customized Content Management Systems from the ground up, I can say that we always tend to underestimate the time it takes to build your own CMS.

It is very intense, especially if you are serious about security, cross-browser compatibility, and user experience.

That being said, WordPress is great, but if you're going to seriously alter the purpose for which it exists, which it sounds like you are, building management modules completely outside of WordPress, then I'm not sure how WP would actually help.

Although more detail on what you're trying to accomplish would be nice, I would personally recommend ExpressionEngine. It's not free, and there's a reason for that. It's slick and powerful, and it sounds much more in line with what you're trying to do than WordPress.

Comment: Yes the idea still needs some refinement,but overall,it would be something like the user can create a website using some basic components(It will also involve a lot of Javascript and Jquery as the code needs to be handled on client side).Currently we are using procedural PHP,but i guess it wont be good in the long run(Correct me if wrong). Object oriented approach is what I am looking for with MVC and some built in functions to make development and server deployment easy.But,with all this comes learning curve,which I cannot afford to be long.So I wanted some advice from the forum on it

Comment: Also,the wordpress feature to store revisions of the pages and blogs is what I am interested in.As the user should be able to back up the data.If possible please elaborate with an updated answer.

Comment: WP is not that MVC friendly. Certainly a move in that direction would be a wise thing if you're looking to sustain a long-term, large app. Your 'server development' issue is a little vague. PHP frameworks aren't really going to help with that (aside from image, file, and DB tools). But CodeIgniter or CakePHP are probably going to be the way to go. Or ExpressionEngine if you want a built-in CMS.

Comment: As far as revision history goes, you can definitely learn from WP and mimic that functionality. I.e. storing revisions in the db and keeping track of the active revision. Rolling-back then is as simple as activating a different revision. I don't think you need WP just for that.

Comment: Object oriented approach as we say is necessary bcoz it brings the OOP concepts like abstraction and encapsulation,also code reuse.Do we make a right call to eliminate procedural programming?Also,if we plan to build a custom CMS which core framework(Either structure or functions) can we follow to adapt in terms of flexibility of use,security and mobile optimized websites etc. Thank you for your insight till now

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Joomla?  Probably a better option than Wordpress.

http://www.joomla.org/

Honestly though, I think your idea is a little flawed.  You want to build an easy to use CMS that users can drag and drop components onto a page to make their website, yes?  But nobody is going to want to build an unthemed, unstyled website.  So now you are back to the idea of templates/themes.

Otherwise, you are asking the user to be a designer as well, and they would style their site.  But unless I'm missing something, the whole point is that they can do it without prior knowledge of web dev (otherwise, why would they use your CMS if they already know how to design a website?).

Even if you do have them designing the theme for the site via an easy to use UI (colour-pickers, etc.), I guarantee if you built up a following for your CMS everyone would want theme support because when there are others who have created nice looking themes, why should they not be allowed to share them?  Some people cannot design, and would prefer to use a nice one they found from someone else.  There is a reason Wordpress has a hugely popular templating community, and it's one of the main reasons your average non-developer likes making their websites with them.

If you are really talking about having zero templating support, then I assume all your components are skinned to some sort of default that your CMS provides.  People would be complaining in no time about not being able to change the look of their site.

Anyway, back to the question about where to start building your CMS, you could try building a CMS for CakePHP.  I believe it has been attempted before, but there isn't a good or finished one that I know of.  There is probably a reason for that.

I think you would be trying to reinvent the wheel somewhat, and I doubt your CMS would even come close to Joomla or even Wordpress because they have been developed for so long, and have contributions from so many people all over the world, as well as communities of millions.

Developing a CMS from scratch is a monumental task, and there are probably thousands of things you haven't properly thought about in terms of making a product that is easily accessible and user-friendly for anyone.  There are so many huge issues like cross-platform, security, rich features, high customisability, etc. Not to mention the things you are asking to bypass, such as templating (I don't know if that includes developing components/modules).

All things considered, I think you would be better off taking Joomla and trying to develop a drag and drop editor or something.  It would be slightly easier in Wordpress though, I think, as it's a simpler system.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.I havent studied it but,I cannot go about everything.Wordpress was recomended to me by seniors as they had some knowledge about it and Zend and Cake are the best in the current industry.Also,I beleive jooomla also being a CMS would pose same challenges as wordpress.Templates is what I am concerned of.Can they be entirely by passed and a custom CMS be built is what my question is!